# Passing std::list<boost::any> as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, boost, std

I am trying to pass a list of `boost::any` objects to a function.

Here is my attempt :

```
typedef std::list<boost::any> Any_List_Type;
typedef std::list<int> Int_List_Type;

void printAnyListSize(Any_List_Type anyListType)
{
   printf("Any list size(%d) \n", anyListType.size();
   return;
}

void showInstListSize(Int_List_Type intListType)
{
   printAnyListSize(intListType);  //compile error...
}
```

Since boost::any allows any type to be passed in the list, I am not sure why there is an error.

How do I type cast `boost::any` to the appropriate type in the list ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is there because `std::list<int>` is not convertible to `std::list<boost::any>` (or to `std::list<T>` with any other `T`, such as `unsigned`).

You can convert it manually

```
 printAnyListSize(Any_List_Type(intListType.begin(), intListType.end()));
```

What you are asking for is a covariant list type. Covariant types (type constructors) are present in some languages, like Scala; if a `CovT<X>` is covariant in `X` and `T` is a subtype of `U` (such as `int` would be a subtype of `any`), then `Cov<T>` is a subtype of `Cov<U>`. This means that in Scala, an example similar to yours would work.

In C++, there is no language support for covariant types. Some types (like `shared_ptr`) mimic covariance by the means of user defined conversions (eg. conversion constructors). However, `std::list` is not among them. This is why you have to perform the conversion yourself.